# Como instalar o mORMot?

Tags: delphi, mormot

O site é confuso, a documentação fala pouco sobre o processo de instalação. Eu adicionei as bibliotecas no lib do path e não funcionou, alguns projetos simplesmente não compilavam. Então gostaria de saber qual o jeito correto de instalar, com os passos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baixe o repositório [github](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot) em um diretório, Usarei como exemplo `D:\mORMot`;

Vá em `Tools / Options` depois em `Enviroment Options / Delphi Options / Library`

Adicione esses caminhos ao `Library path` e `Search path`. No meu caso só tem `Library path`:

```
D:\mORMot
D:\mORMot\SQLite3
D:\mORMot\SynDBDataset
D:\mORMot\CrossPlatform
```

Em versões anteriores ao Delphi 2006 é necessário instalar o [FastMM4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm).

Pra testar se está tudo funcionando abra o projeto `D:\mORMot\SQLite3\TestSQL3.dpr`, compile e execute.

Se tudo estiver correto você irá compilar os projetos da pasta `D:\mORMot\SQLite3\Sample` sem problemas.